# Issue - incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java, types, int, double

In the below code, the following lines keep triggering the error mentioned in the title of the question. I keep trying various approaches with no avail. One approach was, that I tried various configurations of making mid and currentNum a double/int, etc. Please respond with a fix so that this error will not occur again. Thanks.

Lines of code that are causing the error:

```
int arrayWidth = twoDArr[0].length
int mid = (low + high) / 2;                  
double currentNum = twoDArr[mid/arrayWidth][mid%arrayWidth];
```

The method that these lines of code belong to:

```
        private static void findValue(){
        double searchValue; //number to search
        double arraySize = twoDimArray2.length * twoDimArray2[0].length - 1;
        String input = "";
        char again;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

        try {
        System.out.println("Enter a search value:");
        searchValue = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(binarySearch(twoDimArray2, 0, arraySize, searchValue));

        }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This program searches for double values only. Please try again.");
           input = "y";


        }}while(input.charAt(0) == 'y' || input.charAt(0) == 'Y');


        }

        //method for recursive searching goes here.

          public static boolean binarySearch(double[][] twoDArr, double low, double high, double valToSearch) {

          if(low <= high)
          {

              int arrayWidth = twoDArr[0].length;
              int mid = (low + high) / 2;
              double currentNum = twoDArr[mid/arrayWidth][mid%arrayWidth];

              if(currentNum == valToSearch) {

              return true;

              } else if(currentNum < valToSearch) {

              return binarySearch(twoDArr, (mid + 1), high, valToSearch);

              } else if (currentNum > valToSearch) {

              return binarySearch(twoDArr, low, (mid-1), valToSearch);

              } else {

               return false;

              }


              }
```

Comment: Hey! Do you understand what the error is telling you and why it occurs?

Comment: Yes I do - so I actually just managed to fix the issue on my end, but now have to fix a return statement on there. Thanks so much for responding so quick :-)

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory, the indices for the array must be ```int``` and you should accept ```int``` in your  ```binarySearch()``` method.

Comment: "Please respond with a fix so that this error will not occur again. Thanks." Seriously? You know that this sounds like "somebody do my work!", don't you?